# How to put category on home page in wordpress blog

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to put a category in the homepage with thumbnail, title, and views? I have been searching but can't find what I am really looking for.

Here is the sample: http://www.apkappsworld.com/

Is he using some plugins?

Answer (score 1):

That largely depends on the theme you are using. The basic themes don't have this function, you will have to add it yourself. If you don't feel comfortable doing that in PHP, you will have to get an advanced theme that provides this option for you.

If you want to code it yourself, for the homepage you have to modify home.php in your theme. (If you wonder which files to change for what, consult the Wordpress template hirachy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

The standard example would be something like this:

```
<?php

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( "showposts=3&cat=10" );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

This would output the three newest post of the category with the ID 10. In your home.php you would add this multiple times with the categories you desire. Further reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

```
function recent_post(){ 
   $args = array('post_status' => 'publish', 'numberposts' => '3');
   $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ ?>
        <div class="">
            <?php if(!empty(get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]))): ?>
                     <a href='<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>' target="_parent"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"]); ?></a>
            <?php   endif; ?>

            <h3><a href='<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>' target="_parent"><?php echo $recent["post_title"] ?> </a></h3>

            <p><?php echo get_the_custom_excerpt($recent["post_content"],170); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>"><button>Read more</button></a>
        </div>  
    <?php } 
}

you can call whereever, you need 

<?php recent_post(); ?>
```